# conditional configuration of config.action_controller.asset_host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app which uses CloudFront to speed up asset delivery, all is nice and smooth, have this added under production.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://cdn.mydomain.com/"
```

However, a bunch of clients on a restricted network use to go through a Varnish cache to hit my app, and cannot resolve the CDN domain. Varnish adds this header:

```
request.env["HTTP_X_VARNISH"]
```

What I'd like to  do is basically to only use the CDN when this header is not set (clients not coming through varnish).

So basically something like

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://cdn.mydomain.com/" unless request.env["HTTP_X_VARNISH"]
```

How could this be accomplished?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asset_host` can be a `Proc`.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = ->(source, request) do
  if request.env["HTTP_X_VARNISH"]
    "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
  else
    "http://cdn.mydomain.com/"
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that `request` may not always be available (Notably during precompile). You may want to hedge that with an if-statement and a fallback.